# squid　多段プロキシ設定について

Tags: linux, squid

## やりたいこと

・多段プロキシ設定

1. 特定のIP郡(A)かつ、特定のURL(B)のみ、上位プロキシを経由させたい。
2. それ以外通信は、通信を遮断したい。

特定のIP(A)は、B専用として利用したいです。
１の手順については、aclでIPをまとめて定義して、

```
cache_peer PROXY HOST TYPE HTTP PORT ICP PORT ICP OPTION
```

上記内容で、設定できる認識となります。
その他、通信を拒否したいのですが、
他のIP等が通信する際にも使用するため、拒否することで他に影響がないかを懸念しています。

以下の内容を記載を想定しています。
squidは、上からルールが適用されると聞いたので、
下の内容を記載して、一律拒否でも問題ない認識なのですが、
こちらの設定で問題ないかわかりますでしょうか。

```
http_access deny acl定義(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

アクセス制御と上位プロキシへの転送は別です。
`cache_peer` で設定しても自動的に許可されるわけではありません。

まずはアクセス制御だけ動作を確認するといいと思います。

```
acl (A)の定義
acl (B)の定義
http_access allow (A) (B)           # (A) かつ (B) を許可
http_access deny (A)                # それ以外の (A) を拒否

http_access allow (他、許可する acl)
    :
http_access deny all
```

上位プロキシへの転送は `cache_peer` で間違いないですが、(A) のみ転送し、それ以外は転送しないよう、`cache_peer_access` 設定が必要です。